# Inconsistent file content on NFS

Tags: nfs

We use NFS to access (read/write) data in our scientific research group. After a recent switch from openSUSE 11.3 to 12.3, we frequently encounter a problem where a file is created and written to in parallel (using MPI-IO), after which the file contents are not consistent across multiple hosts. Specifically, one of the hosts where the file was created will (persistently) show a different file than any other host. From our observations it seems like the bad host keeps an older state of the file, i.e. one where not all write processes had finished.

Does anyone have an idea what the cause of this issue could be, or what I could do to track down this problem? Unfortunately, I am not an expert on file systems or NFS, but the fact that it worked before the OS update makes me wonder if there where changes to the file system drivers etc.

Comment: How many total MPI hosts are writing to the files/in the cluster?  Do you have more details about the implementation of MPI and the NFS version?

Comment: The problematic file is written to from two ranks, which are located on two different nodes. At the same time, other MPI processes are writing to other files that are unaffected. We use NFS v3 and OpenMPI 1.8.7, using the Parallel netCDF library v1.6.1 to write in parallel (which in turn uses the aforementioned MPI-IO).

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  Are you using typical ethernet connections for the MPI traffic or some sort of fast fabric like Infiniband?

Comment: Nothing fancy like Infiniband, I think, but Ethernet over fiber optic cable. I would have to check with another admin if that is a crucial piece of information.

Comment: It is not crucial, I have seen NFS over Infinibnd, specifically NFS over RDMA exhibit some strange behavior.  If you are not using NFS over RDMA then it is not that big of a deal.  Are there multiple ethernet links between the systems, e.g. fiber and copper/RJ45?

Comment: No, definitely not that.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the upgraded host still has the NFS share mounted and that it's not just writing to the local disk?

You can also try the `noac` option for the mount :

> In addition to preventing the client from caching file attributes, the
>   noac option forces application writes to become synchronous so that
>   local changes to a file become visible on the server immediately. That
>   way, other clients can quickly detect recent writes when they check
>   the file's attributes.
>
> Using the noac option provides greater cache coherence among NFS
>   clients accessing the same files, but it extracts a significant
>   performance penalty. As such, judicious use of file locking is
>   encouraged instead.

Comment: Yes, everything else still works normally and I can access any file/directory from anywhere. It is just a few select files that are affected each time the problem occurs, and while the issue is reproducible (and always with the same files), it does occur only 80% of the time.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke-Lakemper updated with option